# lucidworks fusion Solr search engine query command not found error

Tags: solr, lucidworks

I have some questions with the lucidworks fusion/solr.

1. I want to do some search reporting statistic, however the documentation provided by fusion https://docs.lucidworks.com/display/fusion/Search+Query+Reporting is so bad. For the topQueries section, there is nothing. So my question is how should i do the reporting for the topQueries?
2. Regarding to solr. Now i have some query like this: curl http://localhost:8983/solr/collection/select?q=*%3A*&wt=xml&rows=10&fq=timestamp_dt:[2015-07-24T04:26:49.000Z/SECOND%20TO%20*]&stats=true&stats.facet=q_s&stats.field=qtime_l&facet.missing=true. I run this query in linux system, but there are some error saying stat_field=qtime_l command not found. but i post this query to browser, it works correctly. Any one have any idea of this?

Thanks in advance if any one can help answer me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your first question. For second, issue can be encoded url in linux, and that might be working in browser. Can you try this and see if its working

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/collection/select?q=:&wt=xml&rows=10&fq=timestamp_dt:[2015-07-24T04:26:49.000Z/SECOND TO *]&stats=true&stats.facet=q_s&stats.field=qtime_l&facet.missing=true
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Seems it is not the problem. I am guessing is it possible that the stats component of solr is not enable? Or whether can i check this?